# How to compare the columns in between after aggregation (Python, pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

Newbie in Python, trying to compare the results in columns (df.median == df.mean) in between after aggregation, but with no avail.

```
df.groupby('Club')['Wage'].agg(['median', 'mean']).reset_index()

# Output:  
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-5b0cdf62f540> in <module>
      1 gb_mm = df.groupby('Club')['Wage'].agg(['median', 'mean']).reset_index()
----> 2 gb_mm[gb_mm.median == gb_mm.mean]
```

Answer (score 1):

`gb_mm.mean` has Ambiguity between mean of datas and mean as a columns name, You can use `gb_mm[gb_mm['median'] == gb_mm['mean']]` to get your result.

```
gb_mm[gb_mm['median'] == gb_mm['mean']]
```